# Comparing fields from two data sources in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to comparing the two data sources in tableau and then find the fields which have different values.

I am aware about the calculated_field but as a result of comparison I want to plot those fields as well which have different values.

Any good tutorial or article for the same will help.

Comment: could you please provide some sample data in order to better understand your request?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at data from two disparate data sources, then you either need to join the data into one data source, or define the relationship within Tableau in order to use data blending.
Once a relationship is defined, either in the datasource or with relationships, you can create a simple calculated field to handle the comparison. Something like `if [Datasource1].[Foo] = [Datasource2].[Bar] then 'It matches!' else 'It doesn't match!' end`